# Invalid Column with "FOR XML AUTO"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a typical "invalid column name" in one of my stored procedures, but I'm struggling to understand how any of the popular workarounds can solve my problem :(

My stored procedure does something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects o 
           JOIN syscolumns c 
           ON o.id = c.id
           WHERE o.Name = 'Table_A'
           AND c.Name = 'Column_A')

    BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM Table_B
       JOIN Table_A
       ON Table_B.Column_B = Table_A.Column_B
       WHERE Table_A.Column_A = 1
       FOR XML AUTO
   END

ELSE
    --Do something completely different
```

So... I'm getting the error that Table_A.Column_A is invalid, but how else can I make reference to it in my query? I've tried using dynamic SQL that creates the string up to the "FOR XML AUTO" part and using a stored procedure to tag the "FOR XML AUTO" part on afterwards, thinknig that might be the problem, but I get the same error.

To answer the questions I'm sure some people will ask, the query:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects o 
           JOIN syscolumns c 
           ON o.id = c.id
           WHERE o.Name = 'Table_A'
           AND c.Name = 'Column_A'
```

Yields no result, as you would expect when Column_A isn't in Table_A.

AND... No, I can't change the database structure instead, it has to be this workaround because the table may or may not contain this column, depending on the database instance, and I need a "catch-all"...

Any bright ideas?

Comment: Could you add your dynamic SQL version? I can't think of a way of doing it without dynamic SQL, and getting the exact same error sounds very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code will not parse *unless* you have the column present in the data, because of the reference in the subquery.  The `if` is evaluated at run-time.  All the queries have to parse at compile-time.

The only way around this (that I know of) is dynamic SQL.

Here is a sample of code that does work:

```
   declare @x xml;
   declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
   select @x = (SELECT *
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t JOIN
                  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
                  ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
             WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo''
             FOR XML AUTO
            )';

   exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@x xml output', @x = @x output;

   select @x;
```

You can then place your `if` condition above it and modify it for your actual query.

Comment: Pretty simple in the end... I wasn't familiar with `sp_executesql`, which has helped. Thanks :)